# scheme - contains?: undefined cannot reference undefined identifier

Tags: count, scheme, undefined

I have written a function that accepts a list of characters and checks how many times the instances of the vowels are in the list.

**The following error appears when I try the function:**

> ; contains?: undefined;
>   ; cannot reference undefined identifier
>   ; [,bt for context]

**The function :**

```
(define (count list)
  (if (and(null? (cdr list))
          (contains?(vowels)(car list)))
       (+ counter 1)
       (if(and (contains?(vowels)(car list))
               (not(contains?(vowels)(cadr list))))
          (+ counter 1)
          (count(cdr list)))))
```

Comment: Your function will always return the same value (or stop with an error). Review the basics of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

`contains?` is not part of either [R5R](http://www.schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/), [R6RS](http://www.r6rs.org/), or [R7RS](https://bitbucket.org/cowan/r7rs-wg1-infra/src/default/R7RSHomePage.md) and thus is not part of any current Scheme standard. 
In the current standard we have something that works in its place: [`member`, `memv`, and `memq`](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs-lib/r6rs-lib-Z-H-4.html#node_idx_226):

```
(member '(b) '((a) (b) (c))) ; ==> ((b) (c))
(member '(q) '((a) (b) (c))) ; ==> #f
```

`member` uses `equal?` to check for same object. The others use `eqv?` (numbers) and `eq?` (identity).